# How can I print results from a SQL query in Java to individual JTextFields for each column?

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtextfield, jtextarea

I have writted a Java program that will be able to add customers to a database, and then look them up via a username or customer_id.

I am able to add users to the database without issue. Also, I am able to select a user by username or customer_id and print the user information into a JTextArea for viewing. What I would like to do, however, is print the user information from each specific column in their row of the database to the corresponding JTextField on my form. I think I need to use an array to do so, but I have had no success thus far.

The code I have at this point to select data is as follows:

```
public String selectCustomer() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    String result = "";
    String strSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE username = '" + this.getUsername() + "'"; 
    DataAccess DA = new DataAccess();
    ResultSet rs;
    try{
        rs = DA.getResultSet(strSQL);
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns=metaData.getColumnCount();
        while(rs.next()){//reading one record
            for(int i=1;i<=columns;++i) {//this reads column by column
                result+="<"+metaData.getColumnName(i)+">";
                result+=rs.getString(i);
                result+="</"+metaData.getColumnName(i)+">\n";
            }//closes for loop
        }//closes while loop
    }//closes try       
    catch(SQLException sqle){sqle.printStackTrace();}   
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    return result;
}
```

Now I need to alter that code to place my column results into an array, and then I should be able to simply pull the data from the array, correct? I could be completely off my rocker here. I don't know. D:

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can get the values from the ResultSet using getString (and other getXXX methods) and then use setText to put the values into your text field.

This tutorial may help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

PS I forgot to say, you can get the values by column name rather than column index if you like - this is slightly slower but makes the code easier to write and maintain.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the link. It was extremely helpful. That ended up being much easier than I had anticipated. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like that can help, you can create statement and connection as instance variable so regular you can check if it is open or not. You should use a multidimensional array if you want to return as an array

```
 public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getQueryResult(String query){

            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> feedback = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
            ArrayList<String> feed = null;

            try {
                ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(query);

                ResultSetMetaData rsm = rs.getMetaData();
                    feed = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for(int y = 1;y<rsm.getColumnCount();y++){

                        feed.add(rsm.getColumnName(y));
                    }
                    feedback.add(feed);

                while(rs.next()){
                    feed = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(int i=1;i<=rsm.getColumnCount();i++){

                        feed.add(rs.getString(i));
                }
                feedback.add(feed);
            }



            } catch (SQLException e) {
                //handler
            }
            return feedback;

        }
```